# SQl Storing SMALL Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Nice simple question for the db guys,
Its not terribly important but im curious.

Is there something smaller (numeric) that is smaller than a `tinyint`.

Im storing 120 different values and nearly all of them are going to be `(0-9)`.

A `tinyint` is the smallest I can find and it hold  a value of upto `255`. (3 digits)

### DB:

Im using MSSqlServer 2008 version 10.00.1600

Comment: you could specify the database engine you are using, you'll get better answers :) every engine is different and has his types

Comment: if you want to check the size of a certain type you can run this query => select * from sys.types order by max_length

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numerically `tinyint` is likely as small as you can go (it really depends on the database engine you are using).  You *could* use `char(1)` and then rely on implicit conversion to query the values but that would be needless overhead to solve a problem that doesn't really need solving.  Also, `char(1)` is still going to consume 1 byte, 8 bits, which ranges 0-255.  I would consider this a micro-optimization and not worth the time/effort.

I know you are probably asking for academic purposes, but in terms of database storage, `tinyint` is small enough for almost all situations.  If you are *that* concerned about space consumption, I would say you need to look at other options than a traditional RDBMS.

Comment: thanks,  not for academic purposes, just late at night and I was curious since im building this database for a client

Comment: my thoughts exactly on the char(1)

Answer (score 1):

You can of course manually pack multiple of your elements into one field; since almost every computing system is byte (8-bit) oriented, typically the smallest usefully available element is just one byte, 8 bits, that can represent 0-255 (or -128 to 127) for example.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but then thereis also overhead in  splitting up the data into the display form as well, Im using ADO.NET and DataMapping to my objects